# Does $\int_E f = 0$ implies $f = 0$ a.e.?

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

I know that for nonnegative $f$ and a measurable set $E$, $$\int_E f$$ (Lebesgue integral) is identically zero iff $f = 0$ a.e. How can I show this property holds for any **arbitrary** $f$ (not necessarily nonnegative)? Assume $f$ is continuous everywhere.

Comment: You should assume that $\int\limits_{E}{f}=0$ for all $E\in \Sigma$, where $\Sigma$ is the sigma algebra from the measure space $(\Omega,\Sigma,\mu)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. For example, let $f$ be the identity map on $\mathbb{R}$ and let $E = [-1, 1]$. $\int_E fdm = 0$ but $f \not= 0$.

Comment: @AhmedHussein $f(x)$ is not $1$ but rather $x$. The identity function on $\mathbb{R}$ maps $x$ to $x$.

Answer (score -2):

What I would do is see how you defined the f? Most books defined it as two non-negatives right $f= f^+-f^-$. Then you also said the integral is additive. Thus if you show it for non-negative you are done!

Comment: This is incorrect. Supposing $\int_E f = 0$ we have $\int_E f^+ - \int_E f^- =0$ i.e. $\int_E f^+ = \int_E f^-$, from which we can't conclude that $f = 0$ a.e.

Comment: But if we show one of them is zero that would show that the other one is zero